# PHP variable error in unicode

Tags: php, unicode

Some version of internet explore (ie 11 and some other) giving wrong value like this ????????? for unicode variable. other than internet explorer, the code works fine. I have saved this file encoding as UTF-8 only. could any one help me please.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(val){
var val;
//alert(val);   
url=window.location.href="test.php?value="+val;
//alert(url);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$value="";
if(!empty($_GET['value'])){
    echo $value=$_GET['value'];//this variable is the problem;
    }
?>
<select style="width:180px;" onchange="test(this.value)">
<option value="">select</option>
<option value="நன்றி">நன்றி</option>
</select>                   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that’s rather your fault, because you are appending the value to the URL query string completely untreated. (That other browsers by chance do what you *want*, doesn’t necessarily mean it is *right*.)

Use `encodeURIComponent` on the value before appending it.

---

Edit:

```
function test(val){
  //var val; <- removed, because makes no sense - val gets passed in as parameter already
  window.location.href = "test.php?value=" + encodeURIComponent(val);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, yours is the right solution, I didn't really think it through :P

Comment: please explain some more. what code I have to add more.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this.

Comment: I have flagged your answer. thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I have one more question related encodeURIComponent at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36534847/how-to-give-encodeuricomponent-for-a-link. if you answer for this also will be more help.