# How to give encodeURIComponent for a link

Tags: php, unicode, encodeuricomponent

I need to give encodeURIComponent for a link. This question is related to the answer of [PHP variable error in unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533008/php-variable-error-in-unicode/36533094#36533094). please help me.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
$NewValue="";
if(!empty($_GET['NewValue'])){
    echo $NewValue=$_GET['NewValue'];//this variable is the problem;
    }
$Value="நன்றி";
?>
<a href="test1.php?NewValue=<?php echo $Value;?>">Click here</a>                
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I've understand what you are asking.. `urlencode`?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533008/php-variable-error-in-unicode/36533094#36533094. They have explained encodeURIComponent to retrieve the Unicode variable value. So, here also same Unicode variable used. So, encodeURIComponent is to be used necessary or not

Comment: so, are you asking for a php equivalent of `encodeURIComponent`?

Comment: I am asking above code is right or wrong. If it is wrong tell me the right code. because I have used there Unicode variable.

Comment: People have already answered your question. In PHP, it's called `urlencode()` instead of `encodeURIComponent()`, which is javascript.

Comment: here I am not using javascript.

Comment: see below they gave me best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the other question before you were using JavaScript to append the value to the URL, therefor encodeURIComponent was the right choice.

The problem now is basically the same – here

```
<a href="test1.php?NewValue=<?php echo $Value;?>">Click here</a>
```

you are also putting a variable into a URL context (only this time using PHP), and so it should be properly encoded as well.

[`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) is kinda like PHP’s “version” of encodeURIComponent – so:

```
<a href="test1.php?NewValue=<?php echo urlencode($Value);?>">Click here</a>
```

Comment: thank sir, I was looking this answer. I try it now

Comment: it is working well sir. thank you for understand my question and answered. you are only giving best answer. thanks, thanks so much. I flag this answer.